# How to escape special character in the table line in perl

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, perl

I am trying to access a table which has special character in the name, can someone help please :(

```
SELECT 
  q.user_data.chat_event_text, q.enq_time
FROM 
  swapp_owner.aq'$'CHAT_EVENT_QUEUE_table q,
  CHAT_EVENT_QUEUE_table p
where 
      q.expiration_reason = 'TIME_EXPIRATION'
  and q.msg_id=p.msg_Id
  and p.enq_time > (SYSDATE - 50000/(24*60))
order by 
  q.enq_time desc;
```

**Error:**

> Name "main::CHAT_EVENT_QUEUE_table" used only once: possible typo at
>   ./t21 line 30. Use of uninitialized value $CHAT_EVENT_QUEUE_table in
>   concatenation (.) or string at ./t21 line 30. DBD::Oracle::db prepare
>   failed: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated (DBD ERROR:
>   OCIStmtPrepare) [for Statement "SELECT q.user_data.chat_event_text,
>   q.enq_time FROM swapp_owner.aq' q,CHAT_EVENT_QUEUE_table p where
>   q.expiration_reason = 'TIME_EXPIRATION' and q.msg_id=p.msg_Id and
>   p.enq_time > (SYSDATE - 50000/(24*60)) order by q.enq_time desc; "] at
>   ./t21 line 30. DBD::Oracle::db prepare failed: ORA-01756: quoted
>   string not properly terminated (DBD ERROR: OCIStmtPrepare) [for
>   Statement "SELECT q.user_data.chat_event_text, q.enq_time FROM
>   swapp_owner.aq' q,CHAT_EVENT_QUEUE_table p where q.expiration_reason =
>   'TIME_EXPIRATION' and q.msg_id=p.msg_Id and p.enq_time > (SYSDATE -
>   50000/(24*60)) order by q.enq_time desc; "] at ./t21 line 30.

**Adding complete script:**

```
!/usr/bin/perl -w


BEGIN {   $ENV{ORACLE_HOME}='/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.0/'; } use strict;

use DBI; use utf8;

my $DB='pre14msv'; my $db_user='SWAPP_OWNER'; my $password=`/usr/bin/pmo view password -u $db_user -t $DB`; chomp($password); my $db = DBI->connect( "dbi:Oracle:pre14msv", $db_user, $password )

    || die( $DBI::errstr . "\n" );

$db->{AutoCommit}    = 0;

$db->{RaiseError}    = 1;

$db->{ora_check_sql} = 0;

$db->{RowCacheSize}  = 16;


my $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT q.user_data.chat_event_text, p.enq_time FROM swapp_owner.aq\$\CHAT_EVENT_QUEUE_table q,CHAT_EVENT_QUEUE_table p where q.expiration_reason = 'TIME_EXPIRATION' and q.msg_id=p.msg_Id and p.enq_time > (SYSDATE - 50000/(24*60)) order by q.enq_time desc; "); $sth->execute();

while ( my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
    foreach (@row) {
        $_ = "\t" if !defined($_);
        print "$_\t";
    }
    print "\n"; }


print "If you see this, execute phase succeeded without a problem.\n";

END {

    $db->disconnect if defined($db); }
```

Comment: I have added the complete script. Please take a look

Comment: Hmm, [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm) ' $sql = $dbh->quote($value);' see the linked documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Perl, a `'` inside variable names is the same as `::`, so `$'CHAT_EVENT_QUEUE_table` becomes `$::CHAT_EVENT_QUEUE_table` which is a package variable in the package `main`: `$main::CHAT_EVENT_QUEUE_table` – except that you do not have such a variable.

If you want the literal string `$'CHAT_EVENT_QUEUE_table` to be there, put the SQL into a single-quoted string which does not interpolate variables, e.g.

```
my $sth = $db->prepare(q(... SQL here no $'variables ...));
```

If for some reason you do need escape codes, escape the `$`: `\$`.

Comment: could you please write the entire statement.

Comment: This worked:
my $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT q.user_data.chat_event_text, p.enq_time FROM swapp_owner.aq\$CHAT_EVENT_QUEUE_table q,CHAT_EVENT_QUEUE_table p where q.expiration_reason = 'TIME_EXPIRATION'and q.enq_time=p.enq_time order by q.enq_time desc");

Comment: Where did perl borrowed this WTF from? :)

Comment: @mpapec Perl has borrowed syntax from a large number of sources. `::` is from C++, and `'` as a package separator comes from Ada. As it turns out, `'` messes with naive syntax highlighting, and few people know Ada anyway, so `'` as a package separator is now a footnote of the past, and a useful trick for code obfuscation. Today, few modules working with package names will handle `'` correctly – most assume that package names match `/\A [^\W\d]\w* (?: ::\w+ )* \z/x`.